# Selenium, element hides when I minimize tab

Tags: python, selenium

I have problem with my selenium script, it is working properly but only if I've opened tab with that website, when I minimize it, script stops. I figured out that website is hiding "input_elem" (from code below) from their code, when I do not focus on that tab. How can I bypass that?

```
chat = driver.find_element_by_id("chat")
chat_frame = chat.find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")[2]
driver.switch_to_frame(chat_frame)
time.sleep(5)

try:
    input_elem = driver.find_elements_by_id("input")[0]
    input_elem.click()
except:
    pass

for x in range(50):
    post = random.choice(post_array)
    input_elem.send_keys(post)
    input_elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    time.sleep(10)
```